TypeError on Initializing CustomVisionTrainingClient in Azure SDK for Python: Multiple Values for Argument 'Endpoint'
I'm working with the Azure Custom Vision Service SDK for Python and encountering an error when trying to initialize the CustomVisionTrainingClient. Despite following the documentation, I keep getting a TypeError indicating that I've provided multiple values for the endpoint argument.
Here's the code snippet that's causing the error, with the key and endpoint removed.
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.customvision.training import CustomVisionTrainingClient
from msrest.authentication import ApiKeyCredentials

training_key = 'supplied'
endpoint = 'supplied'

credentials = ApiKeyCredentials(in_headers={"Training-key": training_key})

trainer = CustomVisionTrainingClient(credentials, endpoint=endpoint)

Error Message:

TypeError: CustomVisionTrainingClient.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'endpoint'

The endpoint is only specified once as a keyword argument. I am using version 3.1.0 of the azure-cognitiveservices-vision-customvision package.
What could be causing this error where the constructor thinks endpoint is being passed multiple times?
Is there a common mistake or a known issue with this version of the SDK that I might be overlooking?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated as I have checked the usual sources and found no mention of changes that would affect this.
Looked at Azure docs, didn't seem to be any obvious issues:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/custom-vision-service/quickstarts/object-detection?tabs=windows%2Cvisual-studio&pivots=programming-language-python
